# How to build Gift Cards in an ecommerce site (using Stripe)

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments, e-commerce, payment, ecom

We are using a dot net backend with Stripe for our e-commerce site and a Vue frontend. The client wants giftcards, any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: This is too broad a question to answer here.  I recommend you contact Stripe Support and provide more details about your specific use case so they can verify the use case is something Stripe supports and provide help with your technical questions: https://support.stripe.com/contact